# Refresh Excel external data connection using python

Tags: python, excel

I have a excel file with external data connection. I need to refresh the connection data using python.

I tried a soultion

```
import win32com.client
import os
fileName="testconn.xlsx"
xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
wb = xl.workbooks.open(fileName)
xl.Visible = True
wb.RefreshAll()
wb.Save()
xl.Quit()
```

But this solution require excel to be installed on the machine.

The another approach i thought was:
-if some how i get mapping of URLs of data connection and named range in which they are loaded , I can download data from URL and update the data in the named range using openpyxl.

Is there a better way to do this? Does any python library has a a funtionality to retrieve the connection and refresh the connection?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely refreshing an Excel worksheet would require Excel to be installed.  So your approach seems to be fine, although there may be easier ways.  Pandas has a good library for manipulating Excel spreadsheets `pandas.read_excel` and `pandas.DataFrame.to_excel` functions http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html but writing to a named range is not possible using Pandas alone, it makes you specify the worksheet and start cell at least (fine if your named ranges don't change the start cell / worksheet).  BUT you can add another package and use it along with Pandas (or by itself) to WRITE to a named range - `xlsxwriter` see here: 
http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_defined_name.html#ex-defined-name
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('defined_range.xlsx')
worksheet.write('defined_range', data) # writes to defined_range in the Excel workbook
```

Pandas also lets you read your data directly from a URL which would help in your proposed solution `pandas.read_html`.  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html